# Cannot search with crawled property created by powershell

Tags: search-results, enterprise-search, crawled-property

I have a site column, its internal name and display name is **JobName**, type single line of text. I have created crawled property for it by powershell with the bellow line of codes:

```
$crawledproperty = New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty -SearchApplication $searchApp -Category $sharepointCategory -VariantType 31 -PropSet "00130329-0000-0130-c000-000000131346" -Name JobName -IsNameEnum $false
```

It is mapped to a managed property, named "JobName", and set "Searchable, Retrievable, Queryable.
However, when i tried searching with "**IT**", which is included in the column inside a list, nothing returned.  I also did with "JobName:'IT'", nothing returned as well.

I knew that Site Column that is included content should be automatically crawled, but I could not find this crawled property in search schema and I actually want to create crawled properties manually.

The result was the same when I also tried creating crawled property for this Site Column with naming convention for crawled property, **ows_q_TEXT_JobName**.

Could you have a look at this code, and tell me where i did wrongly?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this site is set No Crawl. I saw the error when having a look at Crawl Log. To make the site crawled, you can go to **Search and offline availability** in **Site Setting** and select **Yes** for **Allow this site to appear in search results?**